# Matlab-Optimization Function

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

We are using custom made newton-raphson function and want to use that function for global and multi-search function. Actually the issue is that can not understand the value of `[b,fval,exitflag,output,solutions]`

```
x=11;
problem=@NR1;
gs=GlobalSearch;
[b,fval,exitflag,output,solutions]=run(gs,problem);
```

-

```
function NR1()

% x0=0.1;
iter=0;
while abs(f(x0))>1e-2
x1=x0-f(x0)/fprime(x0)
x0=x1;
iter=iter+1
end
end
function out=f(in)
out=in^2-1;
end

function out=fprime(in)
out=2*in;
end
```

Comment: are you sure you can use `run` with 2 arguments?

Comment: Yes we know that normally the "run" command required 2 arguments in global search but in multistart it requires 3 arguments. Do you have any knowledge that how to set these variables [b,fval,exitflag,output,solutions]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is, given the Matlab syntaxis,

- b -  is the value of the decision variable that minimises the
  objective
- fval - is the minimum of the objective function
- exitflag - is a number giving the reason for terminating the search
- output - is a structure with the options you set for the search
- solutions - is a structure that contains all the solutions found by
  the GlobalSearch algorithm

That said, your @NR1 function does not accept any input. Therefore it is not clear to me how any optimisation algorithm would work

Comment: Please format your post with adapted [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Yes these values are already given in the matlab help but we are confused how to define these variables [b,fval,exitflag,output,solutions] using our function.